# What is the right way to make another pull request from a fork that was merged before

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I'd encounter some problem when creating pull request on github.
Below is the steps to reproduce my problem:

1. I forked a repo from github. Suppose from branch `author/master` to `me/fix-something`.
2. I made some commits on my forked branch (`me/fix-something`).
3. I created a pull request to merge `me/fix-something` to `author/master`.
4. The pull request on step `3` was accepted and merged by the author.
5. There's some problem on the `me/fix-something` that me and the author didn't notice, so I made another commit on the `me/fix-something`.

That's all, after the `5th` step, what should I do when I want to create another pull request from `me/fix-something` to `author/master`?

Comment: You need detect `some problem ...that me and the author didn't notice`, it is the key to resolve problem. Can you check git server log? you should check error log on git server.

Comment: Why don't you create this fix into a separate branch that only fixes this issue and make a clean PR with the new branch?

Comment: since you use GitHub, very rarely error by GitHub server.

Answer (score 1):

Bugs creep into code all the time. If you recognize to have an issue, you don't have to re-use a feature branch, because that feature branch has already served it's purpose.

I would suggest to create a new `feature` or `bugfix` branch, place (`cherry-pick`) your commit to the new branch and then create a new pull request to `author/master`. This way you preserve a clean git history **and** it's understandable to everyone that there was a *bug* and there was a *bugfix*.

So you would do something like:

```sh
git checkout -b bugfix/fix-feature-abc
# If you have more commits, you can cherry-pick them one by one
# or do something more elegant (if they are a lot)
git cherry-pick <sha1 of the bugfix>

# then
git push # etc.
```

Then you can go to the GitHub UI and create a new pull request only for this.

Of course, if you don't want to do such a thing and just want to make a new PR from your already existing `me/fix-something`, then all you need to do is repeat step 3 from your question.

Answer (score 0):

since you use GitHub, very rarely error by GitHub server.

Let's repeat step 3.

> I created a pull request to merge me/fix-something to author/master.